# Connection Refused Error Coming At The Time Of Uploading Files From Local Machine To FTP Server

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, serversocket, ftp-client

I am trying to upload files from local machine to ftp server  and when this code starts first it store 6 folder data sucessfully on ftp server  but from 7th folder to 25th folder i am getting connection refused error ... There is no limitation from client side for connections and only i am using these credentials for testing purpose . Can any one help me?
I am getting this issue because of mirror issue in code but i am not able to figureout this issue. Please help me

```
package com.epath.smoketest.tests;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;


public class FTPUploadDirectoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n"
                    + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n");
            System.out.println("Read FTP Login details from PROPERTIES file" + "\r\n");
            System.out.println(
                    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n");

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream input = null;

            String inputFS = getAutomationInputDataPath() + "//Validation.properties";
            input = new FileInputStream(inputFS);
            prop.load(input);

            // -Input file with test data
            System.out.println("Uploading file on ftp server");
            String ftp_port = prop.getProperty("ftp_port");         
            int ftp_host = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("ftp_host"));          
            String ftp_username = prop.getProperty("ftp_username");         
            String ftp_password = prop.getProperty("ftp_password");         

            String server = ftp_port;
            int port = ftp_host;
            String user = ftp_username;
            String pass = ftp_password;

            FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient();

            // connect and login to the server
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);

            // use local passive mode to pass firewall
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            System.out.println("Connected");
            String remoteDirPath = "/www/ngage/screenshots";
            String localDirPath = folderPathForUploadingOnFTP;

            uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localDirPath, "");

            // log out and disconnect from the server
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

            System.out.println("Disconnected");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error occured....." + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void uploadDirectory(FTPSClient ftpClient, String remoteDirPath, String localParentDir,
            String remoteParentDir) throws IOException {

        File localDir = new File(localParentDir);
        File[] subFiles = localDir.listFiles();
        if (subFiles != null && subFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File item : subFiles) {
                String remoteFilePath = remoteDirPath + "/" + remoteParentDir + "/" + item.getName();
                if (remoteParentDir.equals("")) {
                    remoteFilePath = remoteDirPath + "/" + item.getName();
                }
                if (item.isFile()) {                    
                    if (!checkFileExists(remoteFilePath, ftpClient)) {
                        // upload the file
                        String localFilePath = item.getAbsolutePath();                      
                        boolean uploaded = uploadSingleFile(ftpClient, localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
                        if (uploaded) {
                            System.out.println("UPLOADED a file to: " + remoteFilePath);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("COULD NOT upload the file: " + localFilePath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This file alerady exist on ftp server ");
                    }
                } else {
                    // create directory on the server
                    boolean created = ftpClient.makeDirectory(remoteFilePath);
                    if (created) {
                        System.out.println("CREATED the directory: " + remoteFilePath);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("COULD NOT create the directory: " + remoteFilePath);
                    }
                    // upload the sub directory
                    String parent = remoteParentDir + "/" + item.getName();
                    if (remoteParentDir.equals("")) {
                        parent = item.getName();
                    }
                    localParentDir = item.getAbsolutePath();
                    uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localParentDir, parent);
                }
            }
        }
        ftpClient.makeDirectory(remoteDirPath);
    }

    public static boolean uploadSingleFile(FTPSClient ftpClient, String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath)
            throws IOException {
        File localFile = new File(localFilePath);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
        try {
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            return ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFilePath, inputStream);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }       
    }

    public static Boolean checkFileExists(String filePath, FTPSClient ftpClient) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filePath);
        int returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();      
        if (inputStream == null || returnCode == 550) {
            return false;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return true;
    }

}




Error coming .

COULD NOT upload the file: \\192.168.10.21\volume1\ngage_dev\engineering\ngage\testing\automated\validation\Build_1.19.1\051\2018-04-23_07-54-39_AM\TC_UA_PSWD_0001_006_1.png
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:920)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:627)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFileStream(FTPClient.java:1980)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(FTPClient.java:1967)
at com.epath.smoketest.tests.FTPUploadDirectoryTest.checkFileExists(FTPUploadDirectoryTest.java:124)
```

Comment: Can you upload the same set of files using any standalone FTP client running on the same machine as your Java code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  I can upload all file if i am using this code given in "http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/how-to-upload-a-directory-to-a-ftp-server"   but i have done some modification in code because of this only few folder data uploading on ftp server

Comment: Are you really saying that you have a working code and you didn't bother to tell us in your question in the very first place???

Comment: So in other words, if you make `checkFileExists` return `false` unconditionally, the code works?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl This code is working but this is not as per my client requirement. I have done some modification as per my project requirement . Only for testing purpose i used this website code and this is working  but this code is not completing my requirement . After doing some changes in code then i am getting connection refused error .

Comment: OK, but you have to tell us that! You are just wasting our time to find out, what you know already! + You didn't answer my second question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl   I just checked i changed return false and still i am getting connection refuse error . at same point

Comment: OK, so do find out what change caused the problem. We won't debug your code for you. It's your task to post [mcve].

Comment: A "Connection Refused" error means the client is trying to connect to an IP/Port (which is the case in a Passive-mode transfer) that either 1) is not listening for connections; 2) has too many pending connections; or 3) is being blocked by a firewall/router. Unfortunately, there is no way for a client to determine which is the case, all it can do is wait awhile and try again, or stop trying and move on

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your reply.  My scenario is  :-  Currently no folder available in FTP server.  If i am executing this code and trying to send all folder in ftp at same time  then this code is working.  when i am calling this method in  @ After then data will move with test case execution. And after every test case folder will transfer from local machine to ftp server.  I am getting this error when i have existing folder in ftp and trying to upload folder one by one .

Comment: @TarunDabbs that doesn't change what I said. Whether a folder exists or not is moot. Testing a folder for existence, and creating new folders, that is all handed only on the command connection, which is already established. Only when transferring individual files, that is handed using secondary connections, and that is where the error message is coming from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau :- Thanks Remy.